# Custom keyboard layout not installing

Tags: macos, keyboard, customization

I'm using Mac OS Yosemite.

I've created a custom keyboard layout using Ukelele, and have saved to a .keyLayout file.

I moved it to /Library/Keyboard Layouts, then I restarted the computer

and it doesn't show up when I try to add a keyboard input.

Why isn't it showing up??? I'm so confused.